# Get the most occurring digit in a row of a matrix and concatenate results

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix `eval_matrix` which has dimensions `(200,45)`. I want to get the most occurring digit in each row and want to make a new matrix `maj` of `200` rows and one column.

I am trying this:

```
maj=c()
for (i in nrow(eval_matrix)){
  m=names(which.max(table(eval_matrix[i,])))
  m<-as.numeric(m)
  maj<-rbind(maj,m)
}
View(maj)
```

But it is only giving me the last row's result in my new matrix `maj`.

What's going wrong here?

Comment: use `for(i in 1:nrow(eval_matrix))` :)

Comment: in general; `for(i in seq_len(nrow(eval_matrix)))` is probably better, as it handles arrays with "zero length" properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `apply()` over each row of a matrix and turn the result into a one-column matrix. In a single line:

```
matrix(as.numeric(apply(eval_matrix, 1, function(x) names(which.max(table(x))))), ncol=1)
```